# Как правильно рассчитать дату на Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый день.
Как можно написать программу на Python, которая запрашивает дату и выводит в формате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date=input('Введите дату: ')
date=date.split(' ')
ans=''
if date[0] in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ':
    ans+='0'
ans+=date[0]+'.'
month={
'января':'01',
'февраля':'02',
"марта":'03',
"апреля":'04',
"мая":'05',
"июня":'06',
"июля":'07',
"августа":'08',
"сентября":'09',
"октября":'10',
"ноября":'11',
"декабря":'12',
}
ans+=month[date[1]]+'.2020'
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

дата="28 Февраля"

def МесяцПоEn(месяц: str):

    return\
    {   "Февраля":  "Feb",
    }[месяц]

части=дата.split(' ')

mount=МесяцПоEn(части[1])

date=части[0] + ' ' + mount + " 2020"

print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y"))
```

На большее мне терпения не хватило. Делайте сами по этому примеру.

Comment: [Документация по форматированию строк в дату (2 аргумент strptime)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Не пишите сразу велосипеды, в python либо все есть в стандартной библиотеке, либо в сторонних, а если нет, то тогда есть смысл что-то написать =)

Русский она тоже поддерживает, почитайте документацию, уверен и под ваши форматы сможете подогнать:
https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#humanize